# Reverse checkbox value in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

Having some troubles reversing the checkbox value in Angular 2.

In Angular 1.x we could make a directive like below.

```
.directive('invertValue', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(val) { return !val; });
      ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function(val) { return !val; });
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: you mean making it false if its true?

Comment: Yeah the value is in my object is true however the checkbox should display as false. Without changing ngModel to false. i was hoping to create this as a directive so its reusable like the above code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why you need directive for this simple thing

you can achieve like this

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="!value" (change)="value= !value" />
```

Comment: Does anybody know a drawback of this solution? For exaple by omitting ngModel from the element? Because it was my first solution but I could not make ngModel reversed. For now it looks fine :)